# Using Recursive Binary Search

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, binary-search

I'm currently writing a program where in one task I have to use a binary recursive function to search an integer in an array and display the index of the target.

However, I'm having trouble with this particular function as it's outputting a different index than the correct one.

If anyone can help out fixing this error, I would really appreciate it!

**My Current Code**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int linearSearch(int [], int, int, int);
int binarySearch(int [], int, int, int);

void reverseArray(int arr[], int index1, int index2)
{
    if(index2 > index1)
    {
        swap(arr[index2], arr[index1]);
        reverseArray(arr, index1 + 1, index2 - 1);
    }
}

void printArray(int arr[], int SIZE)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

int getSum_Linear(int arr[], int SIZE)
{
    if(SIZE <= 0)
        return 0;

    return(getSum_Linear(arr, SIZE - 1) + arr[SIZE - 1]);
}

int getSum_Binary(int arr[], int SIZE)
{
    if(SIZE == 1)
        return arr[0];
    else
    {
        int mid = SIZE / 2;
        return(getSum_Binary(arr, mid) + getSum_Binary(arr + mid, SIZE - mid));
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 9;
    int arrInt[SIZE] = {11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99};

    /// Enter your testing code for Task 1, 2 and 3 here

    cout << "// Task 1" << endl << endl;

    // Print original array.
    cout << "Original array: " << endl;
    printArray(arrInt, SIZE);

    // Reverse array.
    cout << endl;
    reverseArray(arrInt, 0, SIZE - 1);

    // Print reversed array.
    cout << "Reversed array: " << endl;
    printArray(arrInt, SIZE);

    cout << endl << "// Task 2" << endl << endl;

    cout << "Linear sum of array: " << getSum_Linear(arrInt, SIZE) << endl;

    cout << endl << "// Task 3" << endl << endl;

    cout << "Binary sum of array: " << getSum_Binary(arrInt, SIZE) << endl;

    cout << endl << "// Task 4" << endl << endl;

    int target = 99;
    int pos = linearSearch(arrInt, 0, SIZE, target);

    cout << "Linear search: The position of the target " << target << " is " << pos << endl;

    target = 66;
    pos = linearSearch(arrInt, 0, SIZE, target);
    cout << "Linear search: The position of the target " << target << " is " << pos << endl;

    cout << endl << "// Task 5" << endl << endl;

    target = 99;
    pos = binarySearch(arrInt, 0, SIZE - 1, target);
    cout << "Binary search: The position of the target " << target << " is " << pos << endl;

    target = 66;
    pos = binarySearch(arrInt, 0, SIZE - 1, target);
    cout << "Binary search: The position of the target " << target << " is " << pos << endl;

    return 0;
}

int linearSearch(int arrInt[], int pos, int SIZE, int target)
{
    if(pos >= SIZE)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if(arrInt[pos] == target)
    {
        return pos;
    }
    else
    {
        return linearSearch(arrInt, pos + 1, SIZE, target);
    }
}

int binarySearch(int arrInt[], int begIndex, int endIndex, int target)
{
    if (endIndex >= begIndex)
    {
        int midIndex = begIndex + (endIndex - begIndex) / 2;

        if (arrInt[midIndex] == target)
            return midIndex;

        if (arrInt[midIndex] > target)
            return binarySearch(arrInt, begIndex, midIndex - 1, target);

        return binarySearch(arrInt, midIndex + 1, endIndex, target);
    }

    return -1;
}
```

**My Current Output**

```
// Task 1

Original array:
11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99

Reversed array:
99 88 77 66 55 44 33 22 11

// Task 2

Linear sum of array: 495

// Task 3

Binary sum of array: 495

// Task 4

Linear search: The position of the target 99 is 0
Linear search: The position of the target 66 is 3

// Task 5

Binary search: The position of the target 99 is -1
Binary search: The position of the target 66 is -1
```

Comment: Add some debugging output in your binarySearch method, that will show what what arguments it gets called with, you should be able to find out pretty easily what's going on when you see this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using a recursive binary search function designed to work with a list sorted in ascending not descending order.  The problem lies in this line of code:

```
 if (arrInt[midIndex] > target)
            return binarySearch(arrInt, begIndex, midIndex - 1, target);
```

For a array of ints sorted in descending order, the comparison needs to be reversed. For example, this variant:

```
int reversedBinSearch(int arr[], int begDex, int endDex, int target) {
    if (endDex < begDex) {  //failure case terminates recursion
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        int midDex = begDex + (endDex - begDex) / 2;
        if (arr[midDex] == target) {
            return midDex;
        }
        else if (arr[midDex] < target) {    // <- change here
            return reversedBinSearch(arr, begDex, midDex - 1, target);
        }
        else {
            return reversedBinSearch(arr, midDex + 1, endDex, target);
        }
    }
}
```

Without that change you end up searching the wrong block.

Comment: That actually solved my problem! I can't believe it was this little sign ```>``` that was causing the issue. I'll keep this in mind next time. Thank you so much for your help @neutrino_logic

Comment: Sure, glad to help